# How do I remove color from abbreviations?

Tags: hyperref, color

When I call abbreviations using `\gls{}` command, the color of the abbreviations in the document is the customized color that I defined (bluegrey). I only want this color when I refer figures and not abbreviations.

```
\definecolor{bluegray}{rgb}{0.4, 0.6, 0.8} 

\definecolor{black}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 0.0}

\definecolor{bluee}{rgb}{0.0, 0.47, 0.75}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \hypersetup{
    citecolor=black,
    linkcolor=bluegray,   
    urlcolor=black,
    linktoc=all}}
```

Comment: Would you please provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: if you want to remove the hyperlinks in the glossaries then add the below options in the glossaries package. \usepackage[acronym,nohypertypes={acronym,notation}]{glossaries}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to redefine the command `\glstextformat`.

---

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum, etoolbox, xcolor, graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=bluegray,
  citecolor=black,
  urlcolor=black,
  linktoc=all,
}

\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\textcolor{black}{#1}}

\definecolor{bluegray}{rgb}{0.4, 0.6, 0.8} 
\definecolor{black}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 0.0}
\definecolor{bluee}{rgb}{0.0, 0.47, 0.75}

\makeglossaries%

\newacronym{gcd}{GCD}{Greatest Common Divisor}
\newacronym{lcm}{LCM}{Least Common Multiple}

\begin{document}

\printglossaries%
\listoffigures

\vspace{1cm}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{sample image}%
  \label{fig:sample}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

See figure~\ref{fig:sample} or \gls{gcd}.

\end{document}
```

[image]